# Escaping a quote in a dictionary

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a .yml file with dict items:

```yaml
messages_to_skip:
  - service: "test1"
    message: "Exception during timer operation execution"
  - service: "test2"
    message: "Error in pipe 'cpl.service.pipe"
  - service: "test3"
    message: "Unknown attribute with JSONPath"
```

and when I try to use it in jinja template

```
messages_to_skip = [
for message_to_skip in messages_to_skip %}
message_to_skip['service'] }}", "{{ message_to_skip['message'] }}"] {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
endfor %}
> ]
```

I got an error, related to single quote here(in test2): "pipe 'controlpanel".
I tried to use backslash , but nothing.
Could you help, please?

I tried to use backslash

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
You escape the quote using a filter: `replace("'", "\\'")`

```yaml
messages_to_skip = [
{% for message_to_skip in messages_to_skip %}
  ["{{ message_to_skip.service }}", "{{ message_to_skip.message|replace("'", "\\'") }}"]{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
]
```

This provides me:

```bash
[vagrant@vm-local-1 ~]$ cat /tmp/a
messages_to_skip = [
  ["test1", "Exception during timer operation execution"],
  ["test2", "Error in pipe \'cpl.service.pipe"],
  ["test3", "Unknown attribute with JSONPath"]]
[vagrant@vm-local-1 ~]$
```

Comment: No, it didn’t work      
  ansible/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tomli/_parser.py:575: in parse_basic_str
    [11:20:16][Step 5/10]     pos, parsed_escape = parse_escapes(src, pos)
    [11:20:16][Step 5/10] ansible/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tomli/_parser.py:494: in parse_basic_str_escape
    [11:20:16][Step 5/10]     raise suffixed_err(src, pos, "Unescaped '\\' in a string") from None
    [11:20:16][Step 5/10] E   tomli.TOMLDecodeError: Unescaped '\' in a string (at line 14, column 125)

Comment: idk, works for me. What Ansible version are you using?